# Customizing a table cell<td> on my index.htm.erb view using rails 3

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

My   `index.html.erb` page under views/projects displays 5 fields(cells) under my projects tab.

Product, Status, POCs, est_date and delivery_date. I am using the following code in my table:

```
    <% @projects.each do |project| %>
    <tr>
    <td><%= link_to project.product, project %> </td>
    <td><%= project.status %><%= link_to '...MORE', project %></td>
    <td><%= project.pocs %></td>
    ....
    ....
```

So basically the table/view lists all of my projects and you can click on any of the projects to view a detailed view    (`show.html.erb`) of all the fields in each project.

The   `Status` field/cell can get rather large with all the details that can be entered into it.

My question is this. How can I adjust the   `Status` cell in the index view to only show the first 5 lines of text. `If` more then 5 lines show my link   (`...MORE`). When clicked, go to the details view (show.html.erb) where you can view the the details.

I just don't want the index view getting too large and full of too much text. It should just be a quick summary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [truncate](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/truncate) helper like this:

```
truncate("line1\nline2\nline3\nline4", length: 2, separator: "\n")
```

will output:

> "line1\nline2\nline3..."

The last example on the apidock page shows how you can pass a block:

```
truncate("Once upon a time in a world far far away") { link_to "Continue", "#" }
```

So, it seems the block only works in rails 4. If you have rails 3 you might just want to pass an empty string as the omision then add your link after it.

Comment: The truncate helper is just what I was looking for. Only thing I am not sure about is where to add my    `link_to`. My line of code now looks like this:    `<td><%= truncate(project.status, :omission => "... Read More", :length => 200) %></td>`  Would the `link_to` go after `:omission` or at the end after `:length`